# IIS7.5 host headers multiple sites on localhost

Tags: iis-7, virtualhost, iis-7.5, host-headers

I have troubles with IIS7 host headers. I'd like to create a domain for managing mysql with phpmyadmin. I tried to configure with these settings without success.

[image]

[image]

The browser displays the localhost instead of the phpmyadmin page. Can anybody tell me how should I configure the IIS?

Comment: I'm using IIS with PHP, and I found, that not the localhost page is displayed by every request, but the documentRoot setted in php.ini. :S

Comment: Hmm maybe fastCGI is not well configured ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah the problem was, that the documentRoot was overwritten by php.ini. I cleared the doc_root parameter from that file, and everything is working properly now.